# Formula for posterior probability calculation within klaR package of R

Tags: r, classification, bayesian

I am using the NaiveBayes() function within the klaR package of R. My training dataset is below. The Response variable is "Grad" (i.e did the student graduate or not) and the Predictor Variables are "Eth_Grp" (Ethnic Group) and "Income_Grp".

```
SlNo Grad   Eth_Grp             Income_Grp
1   Yes Asian                       Low
2   Yes Caucasian                   Low
3   Yes Hispanic                    High
4   Yes African-American            High
5   No  Asian                       Low
6   No  African-American            Low
7   Yes Hispanic                    Low
8   No  Hispanic                    High
9   No  Asian                       Low
10  No  Other                       Average
11  Yes Caucasian                   Low
12  Yes Caucasian                   Average
13  No  African-American            Low
14  No  Asian                       Average
15  No  Asian                       Low
16  Yes Hispanic                    Low
17  No  Caucasian                   High
18  Yes Hispanic                    Average
19  Yes Other                       Average
20  Yes Caucasian                   Low
21  Yes Other                       Low
22  Yes Other                       Average
23  Yes African-American            High
24  No  African-American            High
25  Yes Other                       Average
26  Yes African-American            High
27  Yes Caucasian                   High
28  Yes Caucasian                   High
29  Yes Asian                       High
30  Yes Asian                       Average
31  No  Caucasian                   High
32  No  Other                       Average
33  Yes Other                       Low
34  Yes Caucasian                   High
35  No  Hispanic                    Average         
36  Yes Caucasian                   Average
37  No  Other                       Average
38  Yes Asian                       High
39  No  Caucasian                   Average
40  No  Caucasian                   High
```

I am enclosing the first two rows of my test dataset.

```
SlNo    Grad    Eth_Grp                 Income_Grp
33  ?   Other                   Low
36  ?   Caucasian           Average
```

There is a discrepancy between the posterior probability obtained by manual
calculation and the one obtained from R.

The formula used for manual calculation is :

```
P(Grad=Yes| Eth_Grp=Other and Income_Grp=Low)=

P(Eth_Grp=Other|Grad=Yes)*P(Income_Grp=Low|Grad=Yes)*P(Grad=Yes)/{P(Eth_Grp=Other)*P(Income_Grp=Low)}
```

I am listing the manually calculated probabilities and the R results side-by-side.

```
SlNo    Eth_Grp    Income_Grp   "Winning" Class   Posterior       "Winning" Class  Posterir
                                   (manual)      Prob(manual)      (using klaR)    Prob  
                                                                               (using klaR)

33       Other      Low           Grad="Yes"       0.641        Grad="Yes"          0.681

36    Caucasian     Average       Grad="Yes"       0.598        Grad=" No"          0.563
```

In order to explain the discrepancy, I need to know the formula  'klaR' uses for posterior probability calculation. If anyone can provide the formula, I'd appreciate it very much.

Comment: Thank you, bd33, for making this post so much more reader-friendly.